# Greasemonkey script, that creates Kineticjs drag and drop canvas over every website

Tags: javascript, canvas, drag-and-drop, greasemonkey, kineticjs

I'd like to put a drag and drop canvas over every website I visit in Firefox.
My Greasemonkey script puts a drag and drop canvas under every page:

kinetic.user.js:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          kineticjs_example

// @description   Canvas Drag and Drop
// @include       *
// @require       http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
// @require       http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.2.min.js

// ==/UserScript==


var div = document.createElement( 'div' );
with( div ) {
    setAttribute( 'id', 'container' );


}

// append at end
document.getElementsByTagName( 'body' )[ 0 ].appendChild( div );





var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 1000,
    height: 1000
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
var rectX = stage.getWidth() / 2 - 50;
var rectY = stage.getHeight() / 2 - 25;

var box = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: rectX,
    y: rectY,
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    fill: '#00D2FF',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4,
    draggable: true
});

// add cursor styling
box.on('mouseover', function() {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
});
box.on('mouseout', function() {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
});


 layer.add(box);
    stage.add(layer);
```

How can I drag and drop this shape over the entire website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of appending to the end insert your container at the beginning so that it becomes the first child element. Also remember to change the change the [css position property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) to 'absolute' .

```
var div = document.createElement( 'div' );
// important for overlay
div.style.position = 'absolute';
// change z ordering
div.style.zindex = '1000' // assuming no other elements is using a zindex as big as this
with( div ) {
    setAttribute( 'id', 'container' );
}

// insert at the beginning
var parent = document.getElementsByTagName( 'body' )[ 0 ];
parent.insertBefore(div,parent.firstChild);
```

Another solution(just using CSS property)

```
var div = document.createElement( 'div' );
// important for overlay
div.style.position = 'absolute';
div.style.top = '0';
div.style.left = '0';
// change z ordering
div.style.zindex = '1000' // assuming no other elements is using a zindex as big as this
with( div ) {
    setAttribute( 'id', 'container' );
}

// append at end
document.getElementsByTagName( 'body' )[ 0 ].appendChild( div );
```

In this case the element is appended to the end and then the css position property is used to place it at (0,0) position of the page

That particular site seems to be using the [css property zindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) to change the z order of elements

Comment: I have updated my code. Thats site is using zindex. My example used zindex 1000 and it seems to work on that site. Z index can be much bigger that for your info.